# Has model binding changed from 2.2 to 3.0 Asp.NetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am attempting to hit an endpoint on a 3.0 api. I am passing in all parameters the same way the existing application does using a dictionary of type string, string. But now i am getting a 400 bad request and it is because of the property UserId is an int.

```
public class ConfirmCreatedRequest
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string MemorableWord { get; set; }
}
```

Here is an example of the json using the original dictionary and changing the dictionary to string, object.

```
"{\"UserId\":\"90744\",\"Password\":\"\",\"MemorableWord\":\"\"}"
"{\"UserId\":90750,\"Password\":\"\",\"MemorableWord\":\"\"}"
```

The thing is i do not want to do this as it not type safe.

I want to know what has changed in 3.0 and has it been fixed in 3.0.1

Answer (score 3):

The default serializer has changed from `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json`, so some of the serialization behaviours will change.

If you want it to behave like it did in `2.x` you can make `Newtonsoft.Json` the default with:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

See the docs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support

If you want to make your current JSON and type serialize/deserialize as they have done with the new `System.Text.Json`, you can read up here:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/39473

This issue was raised by Stackoverflows Nick Craver, in it there are custom converters that give you what you want, and an indication that there is a plan to support "looser" deserialization in `5.0`.